# ORACLE SQL issue

Tags: sql, oracle

I have requirement like in address table I have address of many people stored but the address of a particular person can change.but address table is insert only.Every time address of a particular person changes we insert a new row and change the address in that row and we have one common_id column in the table which tells for which person this address got changed.So for each change in particular row the new row is added having same common_id as original initial row.I wrote the query for getting the latest address(finding by time_created) whose status is N and type L for all the people.But it is failing

```
select *
from address wi
where type = 'L'
  and status = 'N'
  and time_created = (
    select time_created
    from (
      select *
      from address w1
      where wi.common_id = w1.common_id
      order by time_created desc
      ) t
    where rownum = 1
    )
```

the above query is failing but when I am writing below query it is passing and giving the expected result

```
select *
from address wi
where type = 'L'
  and status = 'N'
  and time_created = (
    select max(time_created)
    from address t
    where t.common_id = wi.common_id
    )
```

the above query is passing and giving the expected result.

I am amazed why why previous query is failing giving ora-00904 invalid identifier wi.common_id.Kindly help in understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are trying to make a correlation two levels down, and you can only do it in one level. That's why your second query works, and the first won't. As it doesn't recognize wi.common_id anymore, because you are doing two nested subqueries to find the latest date.

```
...
and time_created = (
    select time_created -- Here it would still be recognized
    from (
      select *          -- Here it won't anymore
...
```

Comment: Thanks Filipe. bur 2 level down sql recognized.I just check for employee DB to know all employees who work in all projects.Its working fine

Comment: select * from employee e where not exists (select * from project p where not exists (select * from works_on wo where e.name=wo.name and wo.prj_name=p.prj_name));

2 leval down employee e is detected

Comment: That's not the same thing. those are subqueries. i am talking about : select * from (select * from (select * from table1)). The second select can connect to 1st and 3rd, but the 3rd can't connect with first. Like in the query to get rownum that you use, you have two levels on that query, and in the query that works you have only one.